# How can I edit the description field of a Kubernetes cluster in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to edit the description field of a Kubernetes cluster deployed in Google's Container Engine.

I can see the description when I enter the cluster's page from the Container Engine page of Google Cloud platform, and from the command line using the line

```
gcloud beta container clusters describe <container_id>
```

But I can't find any REST or command line API to **edit** this field.
It is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not currently possible to edit the description field. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

By looking into Google Container Engine API [1], it doesn't seem possible at this moment. The `projects.zones.clusters.update` method can only update the following parameters:

- desiredNodeVersion
- desiredMonitoringService
- desiredAddonsConfig

You can of course create new cluster and recreate the resources, however it seems a bit of an overkill, I guess.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters/update#ClusterUpdate